# How do I implement a basic node Stream.Readable example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm trying to learn streams and am having a little bit of an issue getting it to work right.

For this example, I'd simply like to push a static object to the stream and pipe that to my servers response.

Here's what I have so far, but a lot of it doesn't work. If I could even just get the stream to output to console, I can figure out how to pipe it to my response.

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var MyStream = function(options) {
  Readable.call(this);
};

MyStream.prototype._read = function(n) {
  this.push(chunk);
};

var stream = new MyStream({objectMode: true});
s.push({test: true});

request.reply(s);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your current code.

1. The request stream is most likely a buffer mode stream: this means that you can't write objects into it. Fortunately, you don't pass through the options to the `Readable` constructor so your mistake doesn't cause any trouble, but semantically this is wrong and will not produce the expected results.
2. You call the constructor of `Readable`, but don't inherit the prototype properties. You should use [`util.inherits()`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) to subclass `Readable`.
3. The `chunk` variable isn't defined anywhere in your code sample.

Here is a working example:

```
var util = require('util');
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var MyStream = function(options) {
  Readable.call(this, options); // pass through the options to the Readable constructor
  this.counter = 1000;
};

util.inherits(MyStream, Readable); // inherit the prototype methods

MyStream.prototype._read = function(n) {
  this.push('foobar');
  if (this.counter-- === 0) { // stop the stream
    this.push(null);
  }
};

var mystream = new MyStream();
mystream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: I'm confused about how to push stuff to the stream. I see you're pushing foobar, but I need to push stuff to the mystream instance. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you run the code? The `this.push()` function call means *push the data to reading queue*. This means that everything you push will be available for the consumers of the stream (here, this is the `process.stdout` stream).

Comment: You should also read the [Stream Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook), especially the *creating a readable stream* section.

Comment: Because the object's prototype is stream.Readable, yes

Comment: How does this readable stream get any data? It's unclear. It would be better to implement the _read method to read data from a file.

Comment: Readable streams are the most non-intuitive thing in the node.js world.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a variation of [Paul Mougel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20709307/10824322) using ES6. It implements a countdown stream from a positive `counter` down to `0` (the counter defaults to 1000). Then we create a stream `counter` of 100, which is piped into the writable stream `process.stdout`:

```js
const { Readable } = require('stream');

class CountdownStream extends Readable {
  constructor(counter, options) {
    super(options);
    this._counter = (!isNaN(counter) && counter > 0) ? counter : 1000;
  }

  _read(size) {
    if (this._counter == 0) {
      this.push(this._counter.toString());
      this.push(null);
    }
    else {
      this.push(this._counter + "\n");
    }
    this._counter -= 1;
  }
}

const counter = new CountdownStream(100);
counter.pipe(process.stdout);
```